# Proxy chaining more than 2 proxy in C#

Tags: c#

[HttpWebRequest through two proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581625/httpwebrequest-through-two-proxies)
i read this example ,but i didnt understand. its for 2 proxy chaining .i need to do it more than 5 times.

there is an application called proxifier .( it may help to clarify) 
https://www.proxifier.com/documentation/v3/chain.htm

**question:**
how can i do  proxy chaining ?
proxy chaining which i mention is like this:

```
my ip -> proxy1 -> proxy2 -> proxy3 -> proxy4 -> proxy5 -> website (ex. google.com )
```

**in words:**
i don't directly connect to a website. rather i connect to p1. p1 connects to p2 . ... p5 connects to google.com

**edit**

this is the example of the question i mentioned above. i didnt understand which part is repeating .

```
string host = "encrypted.google.com";
string proxy2 = "213.240.237.149";//host;
int proxyPort2 = 3128;//443;
string proxy = "180.183.236.63";//host;
int proxyPort = 3128;//443;

byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
int bytes;

// Connect to the 1st proxy
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(proxy, proxyPort);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

// Establish tunnel to 2nd proxy
byte[] tunnelRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("CONNECT {0}:{1}  HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:{0}\r\n\r\n", proxy2, proxyPort2));
stream.Write(tunnelRequest, 0, tunnelRequest.Length);
stream.Flush();

// Read response to CONNECT request
// There should be loop that reads multiple packets
bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
Console.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));

// Establish tunnel to target host
tunnelRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("CONNECT {0}:443  HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:{0}\r\n\r\n", host));
stream.Write(tunnelRequest, 0, tunnelRequest.Length);
stream.Flush();

// Read response to CONNECT request
// There should be loop that reads multiple packets
bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
Console.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));

// Wrap into SSL stream
SslStream sslStream2 = new SslStream(stream);
sslStream2.AuthenticateAsClient(host);

// Send request
byte[] request = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("GET https://{0}/  HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {0}\r\n\r\n", host));
sslStream2.Write(request, 0, request.Length);
sslStream2.Flush();

// Read response
do
{
    bytes = sslStream2.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Console.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));
} while (bytes != 0);

client.Close();
Console.ReadKey();
```

if someone can point me to the rgiht direction. i'd really appreciate it .

Comment: If you didn't understand the 2 proxy example then go and read it again, play with it, do whatever help you to understand it. If you don't understand how it works for two then you aren't going to have any more luck with the five proxy version. That having been said there probably isn't much more to understand, you just need to connect to more proxies which makes this pretty much a duplicate of that question. If you are having problems with that answer then ask questions there.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? If you think this makes you any more anonymous than a single proxy you are incorrect

Comment: any of the proxy doesnt log or out of reach(politic ). you are untracable. the more  the chain is longer that chance increases.  it may take years  if the chain is longer ..( source: internet)